# Multiple selection from array, display result (Angularjs)

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am working on Ionic.
I would like from a the side-menu to select (toogle) some criteria. Here is the html :

```
 <div ng-app="app">
 <div data-ng-controller="dishTypeListController">
<h1 class="featured_in_mag_name">Available filters criteria</h1>
    <div class="listing_venue_types_filter_page">
    <div class="input_dishtype_selection " 
            data-ng-repeat="dishType in dishTypeList"
            ng-class="{'filter_selected':selection.indexOf($index) != -1}"
                ng-click="toggle($index)">
                {{dishType.name}}</div>                 
    </div> <!-- listing_venue_types_filter_page-->
</div>
```

data is coming from an  array :

var wmapp = angular.module('app', []);

```
 wmapp.controller('dishTypeListController', function($scope) {
$scope.dishTypeList = [
    {'name': 'Meat '},
    {'name': 'Soup'},
    {'name': 'Fish'},
    {'name': 'Fruits'},
    {'name': 'entree'},
    {'name': 'snack'}
];
$scope.selection = [];

$scope.toggle = function (idx) {
    var pos = $scope.selection.indexOf(idx);
    if (pos == -1) {
        $scope.selection.push(idx);
    } else {
        $scope.selection.splice(pos, 1);
    }
};
```

})

How can I indicate the toogling on the objects above are to be used as a selection-criterias to print a ng-repeat  ?

I had tried tp put a jsfiddle together to illustrate without beeing able to complete it,  https://jsfiddle.net/bmun0mkx/
Hope this is clear
thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Updated the jsfiddle using the angular pub/sub mechanism. https://jsfiddle.net/bmun0mkx/1/

Comment: thanks @shakib struggling now with implementation locally, but jsfiddle works as wanted